# What does alpha mean in OpenCV fisheye camera model?

Tags: opencv, camera-calibration, fisheye

I'm trying to implement the OpenCV fisheye camera model in OpenGL shader, so I checked the [OpenCV document](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/db/d58/group__calib3d__fisheye.html).

I don't understand what "α" mean in this function:

```
u=fx(x′+αy′)+cx
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is for skew.

The following can be seen in the explanation of the argument of `fisheye::calibrate`

> fisheye::CALIB_FIX_SKEW Skew coefficient (alpha) is set to zero and stay zero.